# "Spawn unknown" error while using npm's OpenFin

Tags: npm, spawn, openfin

I installed **OpenFin-cli** using **npm** on **windows 10**. After OpenFin was installed, I tried to test it using the command 
    `openfin -l -u https://apple.com` 
on cmd. I get the following error:

[image: Error I get]

I have:
**Node version 6.11.2**

Link to OpenFin documentation that I referred: https://openfin.co/documentation/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

Can you try deleting the %LOCALAPPDATA%/OpenFin directory & re-running or downloading the OpenFinRVM.exe as suggested in this [github issue](https://github.com/openfin/openfin-cli/issues/34)

You can also try just manually launching the RVM by invoking the .exe with --config=http://yourappjsonurl.json

I believe the asset wasn't fully retrieved